# Chern character of Hom-sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

I'm reading the book about moduli spaces by Huybrechts and Lehn, and i'm stuck understanding a proof, it is Theorem 6.1.8.:

Given a K3-surface $X$ and a 2-dimensional space $M$, coherent and torsion free sheafs $F$ on $X$ and $E$ on $M\times X$. We have projections $p,q$ from $M\times X$ to $M$ and $X$ resp.

They claim the class $a:=ch(p_{\*}\mathcal{H}om(q^{\*}F,E))$ as an element in $H^{\*}(M,\mathbb{Q})$, where $p_{\*}\mathcal{H}om(q^{\*}F,E)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^2 (-1)^i \mathcal{E}xt^i_p(q^{\*}F,E)$, only depends on the classes of $ch(q^{\*}F)$ and $ch(E)$ as elements in $H^{\*}(M\times X,\mathbb{Q})$, where $\mathcal{E}xt_p^i(q^{\*}F,E)=R^i(p_{\*}\mathcal{H}om(q^{\*}F,E))$.

So using Grothendieck-Riemann-Roch as suggested shows:
$ch(\sum\limits_{i=0}^2 (-1)^i \mathcal{E}xt^i_p(q^{\*}F,E))td(M)=p_{\*}(ch(\mathcal{H}om(q^{\*}F,E)td(M\times X))$

Here i am stuck. Why does this show that $a$ only depends on $ch(E)$ and $ch(q^{\*}F)$. I think one has to show that $ch(\mathcal{H}om(q^{\*}F,E))$ only depends on this classes, but i can't see why.

Comment: I don't have Huybrechts-Lehn in front of me, but it seems from
what your are saying that $\mathcal{H}om(-,-)$ really means the class
of $mathbb{R}\mathcal{H}om(-,-)$ in the Grothendieck group.
So that resolving the first entry by vector bundles is the right thing to do.

Comment: That should read $\mathbb{R}\mathcal{H}om(-,-)$

Comment: When you post a question on a specific proof in a specific textbook, please indicate which proof you are talking about (e.g. give a page number). That way, others could see if you have omitted some assumptions, or misunderstood s.th. that's not apparent from your question alone.

Comment: You are right AByer. I changed the question to show where i'm stuck and added the Theorem number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you apply ${\mathcal H}om(-,E)$ to a resolution of a sheaf $G$, you obtain a complex, the cohomology of which are ${\mathcal E}xt^i(G,E)$, hence by additivity of the Chern character, the alternating sum of Chern characters of the terms of the complex equals the alternating sum of Chern characters of the Ext sheaves.

Comment: Yes, i see that. But the class i'm looking at, there are the relative Ext-sheaves, i.e. $\mathcal{E}xt_p^i(M,N)$ which are the right derived functors of $p_{\*}\mathcal{H}om(M,N)$, where $p$ is the projection mentioned in my question.

Comment: All the same, if you apply the functor $Rp_*\circ R{\mathcal H}om(-,E)$ to a resolution, you obtain a complex, the cohomology of which are ${\mathcal E}xt^i_p(G,E)$.

Comment: But why does this show that the classes only depend on the two given one? I changed my question to make it clearer where i'm stuck.

Answer (score 1):

This was to long for a comment, so i post this as an answer: Using Sasha's answer i tried my best, and here are my computations. Feel free to report any mistakes.

Take a locally free resolution $G_{\*} \rightarrow q^{\*}F$. Then we have $\mathcal{E}xt_p^i(q^{\*}F,E)=h^i(\mathcal{H}om_p(G_{\*},E))$, where $h^i = ker(d_i)/im(d_{i-1})$. Now:

$ch(\sum\limits_{i=0}^2(-1)^i \mathcal{E}xt_p^i(q^{\*}F,E))=ch(\sum\limits_{i=0}^2 (-1)^i h^i(\mathcal{H}om_p(G_{\*},E)))$ 
$= ch(ker(d_0))-ch(ker(d_1)/im(d_0))+ch(coker(d_1))$
$=ch(ker(d_0))+ch(im(d_0))-ch(ker(d_1))-ch(im(d_1))+ch(\mathcal{H}om_p(G_2,E))$
$ch(ker(d_0)\oplus im(d_0))-ch(ker(d_1)\oplus im(d_1))+ch(\mathcal{H}om_p(G_2,E))$
$ch(\mathcal{H}om_p(G_0,E))-ch(\mathcal{H}om_p(G_1,E))+ch(\mathcal{H}om_p(G_2,E))$ (1)

Now one uses Grothendieck-Riemann-Roch:

$ch(\mathcal{H}om_p(G_i,E))=ch(p_{\*}\mathcal{H}om(G_i,E))=p_{\*}(ch(\mathcal{H}om(G_i,E))td(X))$

Now the $G_i$ are locally free, so $ch(\mathcal{H}om(G_i,E))=ch(G_i^{\*})ch(E)$ and (1) gives:

$p_{\*}(ch(G_0^{\*})ch(E)td(X))-p_{\*}(ch(G_1^{\*})ch(E)td(X))+p_{\*}(ch(G_2^{\*})ch(E)td(X))$

which is $p_{\*}((\sum\limits_{i=0}^2 (-1)^i ch(G_i^{\*}))ch(E)td(X))$, but since $G_{\*}$ was a resolution  of $q^{\*}F$ this is

$p_{\*}(ch((q^{\*}F)^{\*})ch(E)td(X))$

So we have: $ch(\sum\limits_{i=0}^2(-1)^i \mathcal{E}xt_p^i(q^{\*}F,E))=p_{\*}(ch((q^{\*}F)^{\*})ch(E)td(X))$

So i think my assumption, that $ch(\mathcal{H}om(M,N))=ch(M^{\*})ch(N)$ is always true, is wrong?